# How to call data from session variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, checkbox

I trying to read a data from a particular session variables called 'cart'.  However, when i execute the method below, the output string is the following `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]`, instead my desire goal is retrieve the product id data value (session 'cart').

```
   protected void AddToCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedProducts = GridView1.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>()
          .Where(row => ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("SelectedProducts")).Checked)
          .Select(row => GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString()).ToList();
        if (Session["Cart"] == null)
        {
            Session["Cart"] = selectedProducts;

        }
        else
        {
            List<String> cart = new List<String>();
            cart = (List<string>)Session["Cart"];

            foreach (var product in selectedProducts)
                cart.Add(product);
            Session["Cart"] = cart;
        }
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("SelectedProducts");
            if (cb.Checked)
                cb.Checked = true;

                {

                   // string data = (string)Session["Cart"];
                    List<string> cart = (List<string>)Session["Cart"];
                    Label1.Text = cart.ToString();
                }              
        }
    }
```

Any further advice, as to where I may be going wrong, would be most appreciated.
Many thanks.

Comment: You are probably going all wrong by storing List<String> in `Session` in the first place, as a `String` does not have a "product id value", but that's another question. I.e. `.Select(row => GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString()).ToList()` is not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<T>.ToString()` has the following default implementation:

```
public virtual String ToString()
{
    return GetType().ToString();
}
```

You need to provide your own implementation by overriding that (in a derived class, of course) if you want to use `ToString()` in the manner you describe.

**Edit:** Assuming you don't *have* to use `ToString()` there are several other options. Using Linq you can aggregate the list like so:

```
cart.Aggregate(String.Empty, (a, b) => a + ", " + b);
```

Or you can turn it into an `Array` and use `String.Join()` (as Rick suggests), or you can implement an extension method for `IEnumerable<String>` or whatever suits your purposes.

Comment: Right root cause, right idea but saying "override" is unclear. You can only override by creating a new type. Better in this case to create a helper method that takes a `IList<string>` and creates the markup you want in the form of a string.